# ios 10 simulator : UIImagePickerController stuck when I select video from library and select choose button

Tags: ios, video, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10

I am facing below issue :

iOS 10 simulator : UIImagePickerController stuck when I select video from library and select choose button.
I have set privacy keys in plist also.See below image.

[image]

in iOS 9 simulator it works fine. But not working in iOS 10 simulator. 
Any one has idea?

Any help will be appriciated. Thanks in advance....